# Java: Method is invoked with null parameter using reflection on protected method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to invoke a protected method on a class that is extending from an abstract class that contains the overridden method.

Basically the method is abstract so no super is required, but when i try to invoke the protected method in a test using reflection, the parameter received seems to be null.. or at least that's what the debugger displays.

The test function is like this:

```
@Test
void updateMetrics() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    final BatteryMetric batteryMetric = new BatteryMetric(mockContext);
    final Method method = BatteryMetric.class.getDeclaredMethod("updateValues", Intent.class);
    final Intent intentValues = new Intent();

    intentValues.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
    intentValues.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 30);
    intentValues.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 50);
    intentValues.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 1);
    intentValues.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD);

    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(batteryMetric, intentValues);
    method.setAccessible(false);
}
```

And the method that i am invoking is like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateValues(Intent intent) {
    final int maximumBattery = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    final int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0) / 10;
    final int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100 / maximumBattery;
    final int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);
    final int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);

    this.metrics.put(LABEL_TEMPERATURE, temperature);
    this.metrics.put(LABEL_PLUGGED, plugged);
    this.metrics.put(LABEL_HEALTH, health);
    this.metrics.put(LABEL_LEVEL, level);
}
```

The abstract class that contains the abstract method is like this:

```
public abstract class BaseMetric {
    protected final Map<String, Integer> metrics = new HashMap<>();

    protected final Context context;

    protected BaseMetric(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public abstract void start();

    public abstract void stop();

    protected abstract void updateValues(Intent intent);

    public Map<String, Integer> getMetrics() {
        return this.metrics;
    }
}
```

When ignoring what the debugger displays, all variables in the function take a value of 0 instead of default. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: `updateValues` is in `BatteryMetric`? or in the abstract class?

Comment: @Eugene `BatteryMetric` is extending from the abstract class, which is where the abstract method is. So yes.

Comment: I see that you use `getDeclaredMethod`, so it is in `BatteryMetric`. you do not need `method.setAccessible(true);` in this case, neither this should happen. you need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Eugene i added the code of the abstract class just so this is more complete. but i don't see what other example to give if this is literally what i am trying to do

Comment: a minimal example is like a repo which I can import and reproduce...